# Why can't I play alien arena 7.51?

Tags: 11.10, 64-bit, games

Alien arena 7.51 is not working at all in either Unity or GNOME Shell. I am using a Thinkpad T510 with nvidia NVS 3100 discrete graphics. When I press the icon nothing happens. Alien arena worked in Ubuntu 11.04 64 bit on the same laptop.

Comment: Hi! I would suggest you ask a new question for your second problem. For now I've edited it out. You can find the info here: http://askubuntu.com/posts/68631/revisions, and just copy and paste it to a new question. http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try:

```
rm -v ~/.config/alien-arena
mkdir -p ~/.config/alien-arena
```

Regards
(source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1882171)